# Get network utilization in c#

Tags: c#, network-utilization

How can I get the network utilization using C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the network utilization from PerformanceCounters.

See [How to Calculate Network Utilization in .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20080315235958/http://nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-calculate-network-utilization-in-net/)

Answer (score 7):

You can get some measurements using [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) calls.

Here are a couple of tutorials:

- [An MSDN tutorial creating a WPF C#
  system monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgalasyn/archive/2006/05/09/594037.aspx)
- [An MSDN tutorial
  creating a C# performance monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516.aspx)